# Accounts.createUser not sending verification email when used in Meteor.methods

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

I have a basic meteor method that does the following

server/methods.js

```
Meteor.methods({
  createUserAccount: function(user) {
    return Accounts.createUser(user);
    }
});
```

server/init.js

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    process.env.MAIL_URL = ""//removed for SO;

    Accounts.config({
        sendVerificationEmail:true,
        forbidClientAccountCreation: true 
    });
)};
```

from the client the registration is called like this.

client/register.js

```
'submit #app-register-user': function(e,t){
        e.preventDefault();
        var user = {
            username: t.find('#app-username').value,
            email: t.find('#app-email').value,
            password: t.find('#app-password').value,
            profile:{
                name: t.find('#app-username').value
            }
        };
        Meteor.call('createUserAccount', user, function(error) {
            if(error){
                alert(error);
            }
            else{
                $("#joinModal").modal("hide");
            }
        });
}
```

This creates the user, however no verification email is being sent. However if I was to create the user from the client side like so

client/register.js

```
Accounts.createUser({
        username: t.find('#app-username').value,
        email: t.find('#app-email').value,
        password: t.find('#app-password').value,
        profile:{
            name: t.find('#app-username').value
        }
    },function(err){
        if(err){
            alert("something went wrong "+ err);
        }
        else{
            $("#joinModal").modal("hide");
        }
})
```

the email gets sent.

The reason why I'm trying to create the user from the server side is because I want to disable auto-login and allow users who are verified to login.

Any help on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Just use [`Accounts.sendVerificationEmail`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_sendverificationemail)

Comment: @richsilv thank you for your response, could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a user client side, the Accounts package takes care of creating the user in the Meteor.users collection and afterwards sending the verification email.
It does so by calling the server method `createUser`.

If you create a new user server side by using your own method like you do, Accounts package only creates the user. You have to send the verification email yourself as richsilv suggested. Or use some other routine that will get your verification email sent to the user.

If you want to have some insight on how the Accounts package handles this, have a look at: [Accounts packages createUser/verification](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L995)

Comment: Hi @Jos thank you for your response. Could you please provide an example of how I could be using the send verification package?

Comment: In your server/methods.js:  
Meteor.methods({  
  createUserAccount: function(user) {  
    var userId = Accounts.createUser(user);  
 if (userId)   
    Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId);  
    return userId;  
    }  
});

Comment: wow it works! Thank you! Just a quick question, how did you know Accounts.createUser(user); returns the userID? It doesn't mention that in the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser

Comment: This line in the Accounts package shows it: [Accounts package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L991)
If this is working for you don't forget to accept the answer :)